# Jsf1.1 selectManyCheckbox issue

Tags: java, jsf

i am working on JSF1.1 with selectManyCheckbox and i have this stuff_

....

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="x"%>

</h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="5">
                <x:selectManyCheckbox value="#{hotelBean.selectedAmenities}" layoutWidth="2">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{hotelBean.amenities}" />
                </x:selectManyCheckbox>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton id="saveDetails" value="Save Details"></h:commandButton>
```

And Bean_

```
private List<String> amenities;  
private List<String> selectedAmenities;


public HotelBean()
{
amenities = new ArrayList<String>();  
    amenities.add("Business Center");  
    amenities.add("Bar");  
    amenities.add("Cable TV");  
    amenities.add("Coffee Shop");
    amenities.add("Golf");
    amenities.add("Gym");
    amenities.add("Pub's");
    amenities.add("Swimming");
    System.err.println("---------"+amenities+"--------");
}
```

when i face this page i am getting only four checkboxes, i tried with layout, layoutwidth but still it is not showing that full list.
Also it is not showing *err* output anywhere. whats wrong with this code?
is anybody know about this? 
Thanx

Comment: could you upgrade to higher version of jsf? Try specifying columns in your datagrid. Or try it without the datagrid. Does that change anything. Also, what are the 4 ones that are shown? The first 4 ones, or every 2?

Comment: don't you need a List of selectitems? You want the checkboxes to have a label and a value. But you only specify the label or the value. Could you post the generated html?

Comment: actually i want dynamic checkboxs, and it JSF1.1 as it is. is there any chance to create dynamically?

Comment: of course you can generate dynamically. But your already doing it semi dynamically. In your java class, just change the way you fill in your arraylist. Now, if you answer my questions in my previous comment, that would enlighten me and maybe spot the problem you are having; What values are shown, last 4? first 4? random? Post your generated html.

Comment: If i changed page layout it affect it but shows first four elements only.

Comment: can you post the generated html?

Comment: try with this: amenities = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(); amenities.add(new SelectItem(1, "Business Center");amenities.add(new SelectItem(2, "Bar");amenities.add(new SelectItem(3, "Cable TV"); ... And so on